# How many cycles will it take to execute in Single Cycle datapath

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64

```
add $s1, $s2, $s3
add $s5, $s2, $s3
sub $s3, $s3, $s2
lw $s2, 100 ($s3)
```

How many cycles will it take to execute  above mips code in single cycle datapath..?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a homework question.

Answer (score 2):

In single cycle data path, each instruction will run in one cycle; so your code need four cycles to execute.